# jQuery Slider - Update Span on Slide

Tags: jquery, slider

This is probably something quite easy to resolve, however, I am having some difficulties finding out the correct answer.

Essentially, I have a jQuery slider that I am using.  Each time the slider is changed, I would like to update a `<span>`, based on the changing of a `<select>` box.

To see the code in action, please visit http://jsbin.com/etusu/edit

As you will see, the `<select>` box updates fine with each slide, but the `<span>` updates only once.  I would like the  to update just as often as the `<select>`, because eventually,  I will hide the `<select>` box.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching the time text only once, here:

```
var hour_value = $("#hour :selected").text();
```

and using that variable to set the text:

```
$(".time_viewer").text(hour_value);
```

---

Instead you need to fetch the value *every* time, since the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) option changes (and that original variable won't update), like this

```
$(".time_viewer").text($("#hour :selected").text());
```

[Here's the updated/working version](http://jsbin.com/etusu/2/edit).

Comment: Thanks Nick, I figured it was something easy.  I appreciate the nudge in the right direction.